# How to write Reactive Aspects in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, authorization, spring-webflux, reactive, declarative-authorization

I need to convert Authorization Aspect from imperative to reactive manner.
Currently we are doing authorization for all endpoints in controller layer via aspect and annotations. How can we do role-based authorization in RouterFunctions?

Do webflux support Reactive Aspects ?

Comment: Have you managed to do the conversion? If so, can you detail the approach?